# Network request failed for fetch() method

Tags: node.js, http, proxy, localhost, fetch-api

Using node js as a backend, facing issue in fetch() method. fetch() method is fetching data from HTTPS types of sites, but not fetching data from HTTP type and localhost. And also added "proxy": "http://localhost:5000" in package.json file for proxy.

Any help would be appreciated!!

Comment: Please add a minimal reproducible example in your question. Otherwise it would be difficult you help you
Also can you clarify if you are having trouble with fetching from HTTPS site or localhost site? What is the error responses?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I'm trying on localhost, and I tried both http and https (created and added certificate and key for that). And used fetch and axios to fetch data from URL. But getting data from the web url but not from the localhost.